# Using id.myowndomain.com as OpenID with DNS settings only

Tags: openid

I would like to use `id.myowndomain.com` as my OpenID URL with DNS settings only. I'm asking how it is done and for some examples of OpenID-providers supporting it. Using Google might be ideal, but I am up for any well used provider.

I do not want:

- To have a web page at the id sub-domain with relevant `<link rel="openid2...` meta data.
- A solution which forces me to have more than the DNS-name as my OpenID. For example I do not want an address of the form `id.myowndomain.com/accountidhere` which for instance *myopenid.com* supports.

I have tried to use myopenid.com by adding a CNAME field for `id.myowndomain.com` directing to my myopenid.com URL `myaccountwiththem.myowndomain.com` but if I do myopenid.com shows me a message saying that the account `http://id.myowndomain.com` is unknown. However, if I visit `http://myaccountwiththem.myowndomain.com` it shows as a valid OpenID url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same setup, and to do that I had to add a domain and create a secondary account.

The steps are:

1. Click on "Your Domains" and then "Create One Now!"
2. Write your domain and check the second radio button (`http://<username>.<your-domain>/`)
3. Skip this panel. We'll get to the DNS settings.
4. On the domain management page, click in "Add accounts" and then "Add accounts" again
5. You should get a page white various textboxes. You only need the first line:
   a. Write your email (you may need to use a different address than the one in your current account, I'm not sure)
   b. In the User name section, put "id" (as you can see, the URL preview will be `http://id.yourdomain.com/`)
   c. Click "Add Accounts"
6. An invite should have been sent to your email - follow the instructions to create the account.
7. Now you need to configure your DNS settings. First, still in MyOpenId, click on "Verification" in the menu
8. Choose "adding a special DNS record" and copy the subdomain they give you (`[random characters].yourdomain.com`).
9. Go to domain management panel in your DNS provider and add the following records:

   ```
   [random characters].yourdomain.com CNAME myopenid.com

   id.yourdomain.com CNAME www.myopenid.com
   ```

After the DNS records propagate, you should be able to log in. Remember, you need to use the credentials of your original account to manage your domain settings on MyOpenID, and the new credentials to log in to websites.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer! It seems that the user confirmation mails does not go out from myopenid.com, I've tried with several addresses. I found some "feature request" place at Janrain where I reported the bug. But it is doubtful if anyone will see it. I hope it starts working soon.

Comment: Damn! There is a rumor myopenid.com is dead.. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20383/i-cant-add-new-account-at-myopenid-com-what-should-i-do-now

Comment: I am trying http://www.own-id.com/ instead. It seems much simpler using them instead for users who only was one ID per sub-domain, such as us).